# Getting unauthorized error - AWS graphql query

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm trying to get some data from the AWS GraphQL API:

Here is the model:

```
type List @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public, operations: [read] }]) {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  sprints: [Sprint] @hasMany(indexName: "byList", fields: ["id"])
  organizationID: ID! @index(name: "byOrganization")
}
```

And this is how I fetch it:

```
 async function fetchLists() {
    try {
      const listData = await API.graphql({
        query: listLists,
        authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
      });
      const lists = listData.data.listLists.items;
      setLists(lists);
      console.log({ lists });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log({ err });
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await fetchLists();
    })();
  }, []);
```

I don't even need any auth rules here, but it doesn't work either.

There is an authorization header, but still getting the error.

Comment: Have you added additional authorization for the GraphQL API?

Comment: Not sure, how can I check it ? Maybe during the API init process.

Comment: using `amplify update api` command, you can see list of `Authorization modes`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your schema to this to allow `apiKey` authorization If you have multiple authorization types. And remove `authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"` from your code.

```
type List 
  @model 
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: public, operations: [read], provider: apiKey }
    ]
  ) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I've added 'x-api-key' header, it works. Is it okay to keep both for authorization ?

Comment: both apiKey and Cognito authorization?

Comment: Yes, both of them ?

Comment: yeah, mhm, for example you might want to only give `apiKey` to read access and `cognito` for all access. If it's default authorization, you don't need to specify in the schema as `provider`.

Comment: Thank you, I've just started with AWS :)

Comment: Also you can use built in `graphqlOperation` from `Amplify`, which will for example handle your authorization, so you don't need to include x-api-key in your request. 
:) good luck